# Crontab cannot remove folder

Tags: linux, shell, cron, directory, cron-task

How can i remove folder with crontab? i create new file called delete_old_file.sh and calling in contrab

```
* * * * * . ~/delete_old_files.sh
```

i already try with `-type d` but still not working

```
find ~/dev/test -type f \( -name "*.gz" -o -name "*.tar" -o -name "*.zip" \) -or -type -d -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

For now only zip and file can remove

```
find ~/dev/test -type f \( -name "*.gz" -o -name "*.tar" -o -name "*.zip" \) -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

did i missed some command?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second form and change the last `+` to `\;`

Comment: so i put inside test folder zip and directory 2 week before. Now only zip file can delete, but directory inside test not deleted.

Comment: find ~/dev/test -type d -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
find ~/dev/test -type f \( -name "*.gz" -o -name "*.tar" -o -name "*.zip" \) -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} +

Comment: no, put them on two separate lines. Both commands should end with \;

Comment: Reza, the second line should end with `\;` as well

Answer (score 0):

i put in two separate line:

```
find ~/dev/test -type d -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
find ~/dev/test -type f ( -name ".gz" -o -name ".tar" -o -name "*.zip" ) -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} +
```